# CASE statement construction with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Can somebody please tell me, what's wrong with the following construction?:

```
 CASE @CountryID
        WHEN 1 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+420','')
        WHEN 2 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+421','')    
        WHEN 3 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+359','')    
        WHEN 4 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+7','')  
        WHEN 5 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+48','') 
        WHEN 7 THEN SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'+63','') 
    END
```

`@CountryID` is `INT`.

The problem is appereantly in the CASE statement construction, as IF statement works well, but I can't see anything worng and tried different types of case construction and searched for documentation.

Any hints would be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
SELECT @String = 
CASE @CountryID
        WHEN 1 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+420','')
        WHEN 2 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+421','')    
        WHEN 3 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+359','')    
        WHEN 4 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+7','')  
        WHEN 5 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+48','') 
        WHEN 7 THEN REPLACE(@String,'+63','') 
        -- ELSE @String  -- to avoid NULL if no country found
    END;
```

**[`CASE is expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)**, but you used it as `CASE statement` (available for example in Oracle/DB2)

---

Oracle supports both **[`CASE statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm#CJAFAGBH)**(not available in `T-SQL`):

```
CASE
    WHEN jobid = 'PU_CLERK' THEN sal_raise := .09;
    WHEN jobid = 'SH_CLERK' THEN sal_raise := .08;
    WHEN jobid = 'ST_CLERK' THEN sal_raise := .07;
    ELSE sal_raise := 0;
  END CASE;
```

and **[`CASE expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#i37590)**:

```
 appraisal :=
      CASE grade
         WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
         WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very Good'
         WHEN 'C' THEN 'Good'
         WHEN 'D' THEN 'Fair'
         WHEN 'F' THEN 'Poor'
         ELSE 'No such grade'
      END;
```

**EDIT:**

As [HABO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92546/habo) mentioned you could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT @String = REPLACE(@String, 
    CASE @CountryID
            WHEN 1 THEN '+420'
            WHEN 2 THEN '+421' 
            WHEN 3 THEN '+359'  
            WHEN 4 THEN '+7'
            WHEN 5 THEN '+48'
            WHEN 7 THEN '+63'
            ELSE ''
        END, '');
```

Alternatively in SQL Server 2012 and above you could use `CHOOSE`:

```
SELECT @String = 
  REPLACE(@String, CHOOSE(CountryId,'+420','+421','+359','+7','+48', '+63'), '')
```

Comment: +1 Though I would include in my answer (that I was starting to write when I saw yours) that in SQL Server, `case` can't be used as a flow control. Just saying it's an expression might not be understood by a lot of people, I guess.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Added version from Oracle to illustrate it.

Comment: If all of the cases involve removing a substring, the logic could be moved to choose the target: `Replace( @String, case @CountryId when 1 then '+420' when 2 then '+421' when ... end, '' )`. You can add `else ''` to return the original string as a default.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 2):

@lad2025 has the rewrite of the code that works (and a good explanation!).  I want to point out that in SQL Server, I would prefer:

```
SELECT @String = REPLACE(@String, v.str, '')
FROM (VALUES (1, '+420'), (2, '+421'), (3, '+359'), (4, '+7'),
             (5, '+48'), (7, '+63')
     ) v(countryId, str)
WHERE v.countryId = @CountryID;
```

I don't think this will change the value of `@String` if there is no match.

Comment: Can you tell me what this feature is called in SQL Server where you can create a table on the go like you did in your solution?
 (VALUES (1, '+420'), (2, '+421'), (3, '+359'), (4, '+7'),
             (5, '+48'), (7, '+63')
     ) v(countryId, str)

Comment: @Nitin_g3 . . . It is called a *table value constructor*:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql.